# Querying/searching multiple data tables using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am developing a GIS for historic newspapers in China. The GIS compiles several thousand newspapers that were published in 92 different cities over a period of 28 years. I created a feature class that maps the 92 places and I created a table for each of the 28 years, each containing all the publications from all 92 places in a particular year. I then created a one-to-many relationship class between the place feature class and each of the tables. So in this way I can see all the newspapers published in that place at any given year within that 28 year time frame. The rationale behind that is to avoid having an individual point for each newspaper being stacked on to of each other.

Here's a link to a WebApp with a small sub sample of the GIS. While not complete by any means, it should give you an idea of how the GIS is structured: https://queensub.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=b7677cb82e014b66bf493aed413ad2a1

I'd like to query multiple data tables simultaneously and get some basic statistics. For instance, I may want to find out the amount of issues a given newspaper published within a specific time frame or how its circulation developed over time.

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. I searched for a solution but could not find anything suitable.

How can this be done within ArcGIS Pro?

The solution must work on ArcGIS Online and in a WebApp.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should first decide whether it is ArcGIS Pro or the R-ArcGIS bridge that you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: What if I don't know which can actually provide a solution?

Comment: If it cannot be done using ArcGIS Pro then I think it is less likely to be possible using ArcGIS Online or a web app. Consequently, I think you should focus this question on how to do it using ArcGIS Pro. The learnings from any answers to that will place you in a better position to determine if there’s a way forward using a web app.